# Unable to GIT PUSH due to LFS issue

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm trying to push my changes to the remote repository but GIT keeps telling me there is a large file (even after I add it to LFS).

[image: Git Push messages in Git Bash]

Why is this not working? I added the large file using `git lfs track` (as you can see). But when I perform the `git push` again I get the same error.